# How to fix the content of a table to page?

Tags: tables, width, size

I have the next code to make a table in LaTeX, but the result is a table that fits the width, but what is inside it is unreadable.

I was wondering if it is possible to keep the width and make the rows bigger so that it can be read in a pt12 or pt14. It is possible to solve it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[12pt]{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\textbf{BRONCE} & \textbf{PLATA} & \textbf{ORO} & \textbf{PLATINO**}\\ 
\hline
Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales\\ 
\hline
Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica\\ 
\hline
Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web\\ 
\hline
Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Logotipo en el photocall} & Logotipo en el photocall & Logotipo en el photocall & Logotipo en el photocall\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida} & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Stand en la Feria del Congreso} & Stand pequeño en la Feria del Congreso & Stand mediano en la Feria del Congreso & Stand preferente en la Feria del Congreso\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Charla/Taller en la Feria del Congreso} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Charla/Taller en la Feria del Congreso} & Charla/Taller de 45 minutos en la Feria del Congreso & Charla/Taller de 60 minutos en horario preferente en la Feria del Congreso\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Logotipo preferente en todo el material} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Logotipo preferente en todo el material} & Logotipo preferente en todo el material & Logotipo preferente en todo el material\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario durante el streaming} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario durante el streaming} & Banner publicitario durante el streaming & Banner publicitario durante el streaming\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado} & 1 entrada para la cena de gala del sábado & 2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & Imagen en la cinta de acreditación \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\label{tab:precios}
\caption{Tabla de precios para la colaboracion}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The table I've obtained: [image: obtained table]

An example of the table I want:[image: example table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE¨!

Comment: Rule number one when creating tables in LaTeX: Never, ever use either `\adjustbox` or `\resizebox` -- unless you want to be known as the guy or gal that hates their readers with a passion.

Comment: Off-topic: In `figure` and `table` environments, the `\label` instruction should come after, not before, the associated `\caption` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever, ever use the `\resizebox` macro or the `adjustbox` environment to shoe-horn tables into the width of the text block. No exceptions.

For the table at hand, you clearly need to allow line breaks in virtually every cell. I therefore suggest you load the `tabularx` package and employ its eponymous `tabularx` environment, with an overall width of `\textwidth`, and the `X` column type to typeset the table.

The following screenshot shows the first few rows of the resulting table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

%%\usepackage{adjustbox} % not gonna use this package!

\usepackage{iftex} % for '\ifpdftex' macro
\ifpdftex % we're using pdfLaTeX
  %%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\else     % we're using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set margins as needed
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\mygray[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
% Modified 'X' column type that suspends full justification
% while still allowing hyphenation in narrow cells:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}      % default value: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|} 
\hline
\textbf{BRONCE} & \textbf{PLATA} & \textbf{ORO} & \textbf{PLATINO}** \\ 
\hline 
Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales \\ 
\hline
Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica \\ 
\hline
Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web \\ 
\hline
Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 \\ 
\hline
\mygray{Logotipo en el photocall} & Logotipo en el photocall & Logotipo en el photocall & Logotipo en el photocall \\ 
\hline
\mygray{Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida} & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida \\ 
\hline
\mygray{Stand en la Feria del Congreso} & Stand pequeño en la Feria del Congreso & Stand mediano en la Feria del Congreso & Stand preferente en la Feria del Congreso \\ 
\hline
\mygray{Charla\slash Taller en la Feria del Congreso} & \mygray{Charla\slash Taller en la Feria del Congreso} & Charla\slash Taller de 45 minutos en la Feria del Congreso & Charla\slash Taller de 60 minutos en horario preferente en la Feria del Congreso \\ 
\hline
\mygray{Logotipo preferente en todo el material} & \mygray{Logotipo preferente en todo el material} & Logotipo preferente en todo el material & Logotipo preferente en todo el material \\ 
\hline
\mygray{Banner publicitario durante el streaming} & \mygray{Banner publicitario durante el streaming} & Banner publicitario durante el streaming & Banner publicitario durante el streaming \\ 
\hline
\mygray{2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado} & \mygray{2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado} & 1 entrada para la cena de gala del sábado & 2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado \\ 
\hline
\mygray{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & \mygray{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & \mygray{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria \\ 
\hline
\mygray{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & \mygray{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & \mygray{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & Imagen en la cinta de acreditación \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Tabla de precios para la colaboracion}
\label{tab:precios}  % be sure to place \label **after** \caption
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the explanation was amazing and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|C|} 
\hline
\textbf{BRONCE} & \textbf{PLATA} & \textbf{ORO} & \textbf{PLATINO**}\\ 
\hline
Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales & Promoción en Redes Sociales\\ 
\hline
Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica & Logotipo en la cartelería básica\\ 
\hline
Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web & Logotipo en la pagina web\\ 
\hline
Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00 & Charla en la EET un miércoles de 13:00 a 14:00\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Logotipo en el photocall} & Logotipo en el photocall & Logotipo en el photocall & Logotipo en el photocall\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida} & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida & Material publicitario de la empresa en el kit de bienvenida\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Stand en la Feria del Congreso} & Stand pequeño en la Feria del Congreso & Stand mediano en la Feria del Congreso & Stand preferente en la Feria del Congreso\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Charla/Taller en la Feria del Congreso} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Charla/Taller en la Feria del Congreso} & Charla/Taller de 45 minutos en la Feria del Congreso & Charla/Taller de 60 minutos en horario preferente en la Feria del Congreso\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Logotipo preferente en todo el material} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Logotipo preferente en todo el material} & Logotipo preferente en todo el material & Logotipo preferente en todo el material\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario durante el streaming} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario durante el streaming} & Banner publicitario durante el streaming & Banner publicitario durante el streaming\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado} & 1 entrada para la cena de gala del sábado & 2 entradas para la cena de gala del sábado\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria} & Banner publicitario en los descansos de la Feria\\ 
\hline
\textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & \textcolor[rgb]{0.753,0.753,0.753}{Imagen en la cinta de acreditación} & Imagen en la cinta de acreditación \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €} & \textbf{Desde XXX €}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Tabla de precios para la colaboracion}
\label{tab:precios}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]